# Bootstrap 4 keeping div's inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a list item with 2 divs inside. I want the div with the checkmark to stay on the left when the screen resized. Currently when the screen is too small for both divs, they stack.

```
<ul>
    <li class="comment">
      <div class="likeButton d-inline-block align-top">CHECKBOX</div>

      <div class="d-inline-block">
        <div>
            <small>Username - Date</small>
        </div>
        <div class="commentContent">
            This is where the comment goes
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

My initial thought was that d-inline-block or d-inline would suffice but it doesn't.

example:http://www.bootply.com/ZVPZFTKJ4A

Comment: So, you want that the text `SHRINK THE SCREEN UNTIL THIS COMMENT WRAPS-SHRINK THE SCREEN UNTIL THIS COMMENT WRAPS` changes into multi-lines, right? You need to set its width variable.

Comment: I want the div that has CHECKBOX to stay to the left

Comment: Yes, but I just know how to do this reducing the `<div class="commentContent">`. I'll try to do this and I'll post here, just 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reduce the width, then your div will fit correctly.

```
<li class="comment" data-userid="{{ comment.id }}" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="likeButton d-inline-block align-top">CHECKBOX</div>
          <div class="d-inline-block" style="width: 78%;/* float: left; */">
          <div>
              <small>Username - Date</small>
          </div>
          <div class="commentContent">asdasdasd</div>
      </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.commentContent {
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and made your changes, but now if the comment  is short, then the same thing happens. I updated the bootly with your changes http://www.bootply.com/6Y85Ptiov2#. I'm thinking maybe just make the checkmark div position fixed and make the parent relative so it always stays there. I will try that for now unless you have something to add.

Comment: You just need to change the container style to 100%. I'll edit my code. It's all about width. These divs are rearranging due to width.

Comment: ok I got it working pretty well with position absolute, but it seems your way is more proper so I will try it too

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making the parent div

```
position:relative;
```

and made the checkbox div

```
position: absolute;  
left:0;
```

and then I threw a left padding on the remaining div.

updated bootly:http://www.bootply.com/lfRCJKCMi6

Comment: It's not good practice to use position `absolute` or `fixed`. You only use these properties in some specific cases.

And if my answer helped you or is right, rate it, please.